# Android 3.1 Dialog not the right size

Tags: android, dialog, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am creating a custom dialog in my app and it looks fine in the Layout Editor, but is not the right size on the device.  Here's the layout for the dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_border"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wifi" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cancel_button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/continue_button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/lost_connection"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cancel_button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/continue_button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/try_again" />
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cancel_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/dismiss_button"
        android:text="@string/dismiss" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what it looks like in the Layout Editor:
[image: Layout Editor]

But this is what it looks like on the device:
[image: Device]

It has that weird bit of extra space at the top and right side and the button is compress vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that extra weird space at the top is the place for the dialog title. As i see on the screenshots you used a dialog and inflated a custom view into that dialog ?

I guess worth a try to hide the title of the dialog with yourDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Answer (score 2):

That blank area is the dialog title.  It can be turned off when creating the `DialogFragment` as:

```
DialogFragment df = new MyDialogFragment();
df.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
df.show(ft, "dialog");
```

Where the `0` in set style lets the platform choose an appropriate style and `"dialog"` is whatever tag you'd like to set for your dialog fragment.